# Login to a website offline and update database when going back online?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have built a website for tablets, using HTML, CSS, jQuery, PHP and MySQL. In the website I've added a register/login page using PHP and MySQL.

Can I login to my website while *offline*, make changes in a "local database", and then, when I go back online, use my "local database" to update the "Live" one?

Is HTML 5 "App cache "manifest"" or "Local storage" useful for this case?

Comment: "*Is HTML 5 "App cache "manifest"" or "Local storage" useful for this case?*"—yes, exactly.  The app cache is the means by which your webapp continues to work for the user whilst she is offline; and localstorage is where you can store the app's state information (i.e. you store a local copy there that you update whilst offline, and then upload the changes to the server once the network is reestablished).

Comment: offline as in "no internet connection"?? and your site is for tablets where is the website "on a web server"??

Comment: yes ,mysql is "One.com" mysql database

Comment: check this solution -- https://jsfiddle.net/2noezzz1/